# How to use np.column_stack to zip 4 vectors with different column dimension (same row dimensions) into a variable in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am learning Python. In my research data, there are four vectors: r(4500x1), gcalc(4500x47), gobs(4500x1), dg(4500x1). In the parenthesis, the first number is number of instances or rows, and the second number denotes the number of class variables or columns.

```
>>> len(r)
4500
>>> len(gcalc)
47
>>> len(gcalc['total'])
4500
>>> len(gobs)
4500
>>> len(dg)
4500
```

I hope to zip them into a vector so I can save this vector in a file. Below are my scripts.

```
import numpy as np
fpath = "./refined_pdf_data.dat"
A = np.column_stack((r, gcalc, gobs, dg))  ##I referred this [link][1], but not work
np.savetxt(fpath, A, header='r[A], Gcalc, Gobs, dG', fmt='%.6f')
```

where r, gobs, and dg are float types, and gcalc is a dictionary and its value is float types.

When I ran these scripts, I received error messages shown below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in column_stack
  File "/user/environment/.../fullrmc4.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py", line 656, in column_stack
    return _nx.concatenate(arrays, 1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 4500 and the array at index 1 has size 1
```

How can I fix this issue? Any further suggestion would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your error,

```py
ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 4500 and the array at index 1 has size 1
```

the value at index 1 is `gcalc` which is not an array, but a dictionary with `47` keys.

I am not sure, which key-value you want to write to file, so when writting all data in the dictionary `gcalc`

```py
keys = list(gcalcs.keys())
A = np.column_stack((r, *[gcalc[k] for k in keys], gobs, dg))
# A = np.column_stack((r, gcalc['total'], gobs, dg))
```